# ListView and Global Variables

Tags: java, android, csv, global-variables

I am trying to create a list for an android app.  The app has a lot of information that I have to send.  I created a csv which is then parsed like the following:

```
public String[] getArray() {
    String[] array = new String[12497];
    try {
        AssetInputStream asset_stream = (AssetInputStream)getAssets().open("information.csv");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(asset_stream));
        line = br.readLine();
        int count = 0;
        while(line != null) {
            fields = line.split(",");
            array[count] = fields[1];
            line = br.readLine();
            count++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return array;
}
```

The issue I have is when I try to create the list from that array I have had several errors.  It's too big for a bundle in Intent so I can't do it that way so I try to access the global variable like this:

```
public class myArrayList extends Activity {
int number, count = 0;
EditText edittext;
ListView listview;
Globals test = (Globals)getApplication();

String[] text = test.getArray();

int textlength = 0;

ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

As a result I keep getting an Unable to instantiate activity componentinfo error: java.lang.nullpointerexception.  Also, because of the coding, I cannot initialize the array inside of the onCreate.  It has to be done before.  What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?  The array has to be a part of the app.  Thanks.

Comment: Your `Activity` class is named `ArrayList`?  I would suggest a different name to prevent name conflict, especially since you're using the `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: It's not actually ArrayList I changed it on here. But I'll update the code to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need it to be done before onCreate? That is the start of the [Activity Lifecycle](http://www.javatpoint.com/images/androidimages/Android-Activity-Lifecycle.png).

If you want it to be done before that, you need to find a place available before that.

Perhaps extend the `Application` Class and retrieve it from there?

What is null in this case?

Comment: I have a custom adapter that I created in order to use with an active search menu and also to give me more abilities to control each individual row of the listview. It says that the GetArray class I created is null.